# Create Popup programmatically filled with component

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Because of project requirements I can't use the `Map` component on render, instead I use a `<div id="map"/>` which I can instantiate with a map.

I don't know how can I add a `Popup` programmatically to it with a custom component.

I know I can go:

```
 this.popup.setLatLng(latLng);
 this.popup.setContent("<div>Simple content</div>");
 this.popup.openOn(map);
```

But this doesn't allows me to set a custom component with React lifecycle.

I was able to see the popup when using:

```
<Popup position={this.state.position} key={this.state.key}>
    <MyChartComponent/>
</Popup>
```

Is there a way I can archieve this programmatically?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean a little? are you asking how to programmatically set a child component?

Comment: Sure I'm sorry I didn't explained myself good enough. Yes: I am trying to add a React component inside a popup programatically

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I wanted by using `render` from `react-dom` like this:

```
this.popup.setContent('');
this.popup.setLatLng(latlng);

if (!this.popup.isOpen()) {
    this.popup.openOn(map);
    render(<MyChartComponent />, this.popup._contentNode);
}
```